# Function of が instead of な here

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-が, adjectives

あなたのへんがお写真を、シアトル市におくります。
What is the function of が here?
　
why not あなたのへんなお写真？

Answer (score 2):

This is a context sentence from WaniKani, right? They don't use kanji in the sentences if you haven't learned them yet.

へんがお is 変顔 "funny face", like the kind you make when fooling around.

Comment: Yes! I recently found a 3rd party site to look at all the context sentences in my learned vocab in one go. 
I see, I thought they where adding an honorific  お here randomly. 
Thanks for the quick response. Sometimes it is pretty hard to read their context sentences since they are translated vaguely into english (this is translated as 'I will send that funny picture of you to Seattle.')  and the lack of kanji makes it hard to see when a word starts and ends lol.